# Can I globally "SET NOCOUNT ON" in TSQL for a query?

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql

There is a stored procedure that we're trying to increase the performance of... at this point we're looking for non-intrusive 'fixes'.

This sproc gets called about 500,000 times a day - and it can call into up to 50 other stored procedures below. - **DON'T ASK**

### Please resist the urge to ask 'OMGz, why!?' questions - but just answer this one if you can :)

Is there a way to `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the top of one sproc, and have it propagate down into all sprocs and statements below?

EDIT: Judging by the first two answers below - that leaves me to ask... is there a way to set the "user option" in the connection string or something so that it works for one 'user'? - any kind of 'secret tip' like this would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no this is not possible to propogate it.  You have to explicitly say:

`SET NOCOUNT ON`

A global change can be made based on the answer by @user92546 but I am always a bit wary about global changes.  The minute you need it you realize that a global change was made...Proceed with caution :).

Comment: On every single one of the 50 stored procedures below? :( ... that's too many changes for today.

Comment: Tim if you want to change this globally you can use what user92546 posted, but that affects it globally.

Comment: @Timothy Khouri - I don't want to ask why you guys didn't think of this when you first implemented it :)...but you mentioned not to ask so I won't.

Comment: Thanks for not asking - I'll not answer that this code is several years old and that I'm new and we're in the middle of production and can't change 50 sprocs :)

Comment: Then you have 2 options - change global (I don't agree with this though) or put the effort to change all 50 sprocs, it really isn't that hard.  I've done worse.

Comment: Not hard... just not safe. It takes 2 days and about 12 different individuals involved to change 1 sproc... oh wait, I could go to "/backdoor.aspx?query="... j/k :)

Comment: @TimothyKhouri - ouch sounds a bit political.

Comment: Not sure what would happen if you created a new database, applied the nuclear, er, global option, and then invoked the stored procedure in the original database through the "proxy" database.

Answer (score 3):

The scope of `SET NOCOUNT ON` is to the current object only. There's no way to extend the scope beyond that.

Answer (score 2):

See [User Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176031.aspx).

Comment: That would do a global change - I dont think that is a good idea.

Comment: That's really using a shotgun to kill a fly.